# Can an angularjs Directive require Itself?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Can a directive require itself?** Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DoZRDZ35tgZRsuBt4mnk?p=preview):

```
app.directive('menu', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '?^menu',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      console.log('ctrl: ', ctrl);

      if (ctrl) {
        element.addClass('nested');
      } else {
        element.addClass('notnested');
      }
    }
  };
});
```

In my test it doesn't seem to work (**`ctrl`** is always *undefined*). See the **[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DoZRDZ35tgZRsuBt4mnk?p=preview)**

---

BTW, after this question was answered I discovered that in this case **the caret (`^`) has no effect  and the controller passed to the link function is always the instance's own controller.** [ **[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/eqvoCoihN4VSXPYaaFbq?p=preview)** ]

Comment: I know what you are trying to do. I tried that, but it doesn't help...

Comment: It's not that the caret has no effect, it's that a single caret `require` statement includes the element itself in the search for the controller referenced. See my answer below for a plunker.

Comment: nice, i upvoted your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should directly define controller function to expose directive API to other directives:

```
app.directive('menu', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '?^menu',
    controller: function($scope){  },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      console.log('ctrl: ', ctrl);

      if (ctrl) {
        element.addClass('nested');
      } else {
        element.addClass('notnested');
      }
    }
  };
});
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/cKFuS1lET56VOOYD5rrd?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

With **angular 1.4x**, you actually can now limit the `require` statement to **parent elements** **only** and exclude the element itself. If you change
`require: '?^menu'` to `require: '?^^menu'` (notice the second caret) so that you get

```
app.directive('menu', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '?^^menu',
    controller: function($scope){  },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      console.log('ctrl: ', ctrl);

      if (ctrl) {
        element.addClass('nested');
      } else {
        element.addClass('notnested');
      }
    }
  };
});
```

the code now works as expected.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/2uDUO0LcgDX7xEuBtsJ2?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I guess here the problem is not with the directive referencing itself. The directive will not know which controller to refer to until specified or defined. To access a controller either it has to be defined or referenced in the directive as below.

```
app.directive('menu', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    require: ['?^menu'],
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      console.log('ctrl: ', ctrl[0]);
      if (ctrl) {
        element.addClass('nested');
      } else {
        element.addClass('notnested');
      }
    }
  };
});
```